# Знаки препинания перед смайлами

Tags: пунктуация, пробелы

Я знаю, что перед смайлом типа **:)** ставится пробел в повествовательном предложении:
***Сегодня прекрасная погода :)***

Если предложение вопросительное или восклицательное, то пробел ставится после знака восклицания или вопроса:
***Сегодня прекрасная погода! :)***

Но вот если смайл — это просто обычная скобка, то как правильно:
*Сегодня прекрасная погода!)*
или
*Сегодня прекрасная погода! )*

*Сегодня прекрасная погода)*
или
*Сегодня прекрасная погода )*

Answer (score 3):

Если смайлик - просто обычная скобка, то лучше всего подвести к нему курсор и нажать кнопку ***Delete***. Потому что можно по-разному относиться к смайликам как таковым, но смайлики, состоящие из одной скобки - это просто за гранью добра и зла.

При этом в любом случае смайлик **не является** знаком препинания, поэтому нет никаких причин объединять его с предшествующим словом, т.е. пробел перед смайликом нужен **однозначно**.

Answer (score 1):

Просто обычная скобка — не смайл. А по поводу смайлов Грамота пишет: "Смайлик не является знаком препинания, и сочетание его со знаками препинания не регламентируется правилами правописания". Поэтому Грамота адресует нас к сайту веб-дизайнера Артемия Лебедева, который рекоммендует следующее:

[§ 143. Знаки препинания в нестандартных ситуациях](https://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/143/)

> Смайлик отбивается от слова пробелом. Если после смайлика идет знак препинания, он пробелом не отбивается. Точка после смайлика обычно не ставится. Смайлик может быть совмещен с обычной закрывающей скобкой (при условии, что она где-то открылась :-)

Comment: Я бы относился к рекомендациям Артемия Лебедева с определенной осторожностью, т.к. он дизайнер, а не филолог, и оформление текста обычно трактует с позиции эстетической привлекательности, а не с точки зрения правил языка. Кроме того, приведенные материалы были опубликованы более 10 лет назад, когда смайлики только входили в массовое употребление и были в основном трехсимвольными, а не двухсимвольными, как сейчас. Кроме того, в то время они обычно ставились до завершающего строку знака препинания, а не после, как сейчас. Соответственно, сегодня эти советы малоприменимы.

Comment: "*а не с точки зрения правил языка*" === "Смайлик не является знаком препинания, и сочетание его со знаками препинания не регламентируется правилами правописания" (Грамота). Поэтому обращаемся к дизайнерам.

Answer (score 1):

Нашла точку зрения, совпадающую с моей:

[На наш взгляд](http://popravilam.com/blog/008-kak-sochetat-smajliki-so-znakami-prepinaniya.html), все знаки препинания нужно ставить согласно правилам пунктуации, а **к смайлам относиться как к картинкам**, дополняющим текст. Это значит, что, если смайлик между фразами, сначала ставим точку (или другой знак конца предложения), потом пробел, потом смайлик, потом снова пробел, а затем с большой буквы начинаем следующее предложение.

Аргумент такой: **смайлики не отменяют знаки препинания, не заменяют их, а интонируют**, что ли, текст — передают эмоцию. Это из разной оперы — точки-запятые и подмигивающие значки. Вот почему не нужно считать, что, поставив смайлик, вы поставили точку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 Так что

***Сегодня прекрасная погода! )***

Comment: По-моему, смайлик может стоять где угодно, в том числе перед знаком препинания. А в этом случае эстетичнее не отбивать знак препинания пробелом. А в остальном согласен.